# Tracking of Contact History Related List In Visualforce Pages

Tags: visualforce

Can any one help how to add Contact History Related List in VF pages? I have added for Created date ,Field ,From and To. But I am not able to add the user who is changing the data. Here is the VF pages which i have written.

```
<apex:pageBlock id="thePageBlock" title="ContactHistory">  
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contact.Histories}" var="c">
         <apex:column headerValue="Date" value="{!c.createddate}"/>

          <apex:column headerValue="What" value="{!c.field}"/>
         <apex:column headerValue="From" value="{!c.oldvalue}"/>
          <apex:column headerValue="To"  value="{!c.newvalue}"/>
     </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Here i would like to add User as well. Could any one help?

Comment: Did you try using LastModifiedBy like <apex:column headerValue="Last Modified By"  value="{!c.LastModifiedBy}"/>

Comment: I tried but iam getting this error.Invalid field LastModifiedBy for SObject ContactHistory

Comment: This is how i have written. <apex:pageBlock id="thePageBlock" title="ContactHistory">  
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contact.Histories}" var="c">
             <apex:column headerValue="Date" value="{!c.createddate}"/>
              <apex:column headerValue="Last Modified By" value="{!c.LastModifiedById}"/>
              <apex:column headerValue="What" value="{!c.field}"/>
             <apex:column headerValue="From" value="{!c.oldvalue}"/>
              <apex:column headerValue="To"  value="{!c.newvalue}"/>
         </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>

Comment: Opps... I missed this bit you are asking for Object history right.... Sorry we can't track Created By and Last Modified By..   Help link https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tracking_field_history_for_standard_objects.htm&language=en_US

Comment: cant we track User as well?

Comment: We can track contact owner ...

Comment: can u just let me know how can i add that to VF page

Comment: Try this <apex:column headerValue="Old Owner" rendered="{!if(c.field == 'Owner',true,false)}" value="{!c.oldvalue}"/>
  <apex:column headerValue="New Owner" rendered="{!if(c.field == 'Owner',true,false)}" value="{!c.newvalue}"/>

Answer (score 1):

You can use CreatedbyId to track the user of the history record. I am not sure why this is not in the salesforce online document though. Source: [Link](http://www.salesforcegeneral.com/salesforce-articles/apex-retrieve-a-custom-object-fields-history.html)

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Contact History, you can only display these fields in the VF page.

1. Field
2. IsDeleted
3. ContactId
4. OldValue
5. NewValue

From tracking standpoint, you cannot track :

1. Formula, roll-up summary, or auto-number fields
2. Created By and Last Modified By

Owner field can always be tracked, if that solves your purpose.